# Antlr: Create combined operators

Tags: antlr

I'm using antlr for parse sql condition queries like:

```
[where] Field1 = "Param1" and Field2 = "Param2"
```

for this case I have an antlr condition:

```
andExpr
    :   inExpr
        (
            AND^
            inExpr
        )*
    ;

inExpr      
    :    (eqcompareExpr)
        (
            IN^
            args
        )?  
    ;

eqcompareExpr
    :   (compareExpr)
        (
            (EQUAL^|NOTEQ^|IS^|LIKE^)
            (compareExpr)
        )?
    ;

compareExpr
    :   addExpr
        (
            (LESS^|MORE^|LESSEQ^|MOREEQ^)
            addExpr 
        )?
    ;
```

and tokens like:

```
LIKE    :   "like"
    ;
AND :   "and"
    ;
OR  :   "or"
```

How do I change the antlr code for add combined conditions with 'contains' like:

```
[where] Field1 = "Param1" and Contains (Field2, "Param2")
```

Also the queries can be like this:

```
[where] Contains (Field2, "Param2")
```

or

```
[where] Field1 = "Param1" or Contains (Field2, "Param2")
```

Comment: Why can't you add them the same way as the existing ones?

Comment: @Jiri Tousek I don't know how to do that, I try add contains into "in" expression, but tree was built wrong. I need an example of how to build dependencies, because here the embedded contains operator

Comment: You're mixing ANTLR v3 syntax (the `^` operators), and in your lexer rules you're using double quotes (`OR  :   "or";`), which suggests ANTLR v2. Which version are you using, and why not go for the most recent version, v4?

Comment: I am using the antlr.net-2.7.6. It works much time, now I just need to add the "contains" method into working solution, that's why I do not go for the most recent version

Comment: If the only reason for using that old version is because "It works much time" (?), I highly recommend you upgrade to v4. I doubt there are many people around familiar with v2. Good luck!

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure these `^` operators are not compatible with v2 (at least, not in parser rules). Again: do yourself a favour and go with v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following rules can satisfy your needs

```
andExpr
    :   inOrContainsExpr
        (
            AND
            inOrContainsExpr
        )*
    ;

inOrContainsExpr:   inExpr | containsExpr;

inExpr
    :   (eqcompareExpr) ( IN^ args ) ?
    ;

containsExpr
    :   CONTAINS^ args
    ;
```

and so on.
Hope this helps